# Cannot use my interop dll in my visual studio project

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I am using a 3rd party dll. Interop.CRYPTLib. I am trying to use it in my .net application but I'm getting this error

```
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {AF6AF735-6D30-4E16-8AFA-FD4317E87D1B} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."
```

I tried using regsvr32 but now I get this error

```
The module was loaded but the entry-point dllregisterserver was not found
```

I used regasm which says types registered successfully but it still fails with the first error, but when I use /tlb:Interop.cryptlib.tlb I get the error

```
Interop.CRYPTLib.dll' was imported from a type library and cannot be re-exported to a type library.  Make sure the type library from
which the assembly was imported is registered.
```

My code is

```
var s = new CRYPTLib.EncryptDecryptClass();
```

Comment: make sure all of the pieces involved have the same bitness. If you ran a 64-bit `regsvr32` but are running a 32-bit app, or vice-versa, then COM won't see the registration information.

Comment: I tried both. registering it as 32 and 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Interop.CRYPTLib` isn't a COM DLL - it is only a .NET wrapper for the CRYPTLib COM DLL.  You need the DLL that implements CRYPTLib (probably CRYPTLib.dll) and install that DLL with `regsvr32`.

Comment: Hi I do not have CRYPTLib.dll in my project or in the bin directory. Is this a commonly used dll? is there a way for me to use Interop.cryptlib?

Comment: @David - I've never heard of it.  Whoever generated Interop.CRYPTLib.dll must of had it.  Check with them if you can.

Comment: You are right I managed to find the right dll to register. I would love to know the purpose of th interop. class